# Extract part of Dynamic Url?

Tags: java, string, url

I have the following URl http://127.0.0.1/?code=AQABAAIAAAAGV_bv21

I need to capture the chracters after code=
but every time the URL is loaded that code is different..
I had something like this but since its dynamic I can not do this..

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1/?code=AQABAAIAAAAGV_bv21"

String code = url.substring(url.length() -10);
```

Comment: use the indexOf method to find the index of '=' and calculate the starting point that way

Comment: use `split('=')[1]`

Comment: You can get the string after `?` with `new URL(url).getQuery()`.

Comment: @saka1029 good point, but that would still have to be split by `=` because it would start with `code=`

Comment: Of course all the answers/comments you're getting start from the assumption that you only have one query parameter. If you *may* have more please say so.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like below :-

```
String code = url.split("?code=")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Android:

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1/?code=AQABAAIAAAAGV_bv21"
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
```

or try the following regexp:

```
(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1/?code=AQABAAIAAAAGV_bv21";
String codeValue = url.replaceAll(".*code=([^&]*).*", "$1");
System.out.println(codeValue);
```

output:

```
AQABAAIAAAAGV_bv21
```

This method works even if other parameters are added. For example `http://127.0.0.1/?id=123&code=AQABAAIAAAAGV_bv21&opt=yes`